# Ant build - JAVA_HOME variable not getting updated

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to run an ant build to generate a jar and i get the following error:

```
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0.b14.el7_2.x86_64/lib/tools.jar
Buildfile: /my/path/to/the/required.xml

make:
[javac] /my/path/to/the/required..xml:11: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds

BUILD FAILED
/my/path/to/the/required.xml:11: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-   1.8.0.91-0.b14.el7_2.x86_64/jre"
```

My questions:
 1. I did a bit of reading online and i concluded its because i am pointing it to the JRE and not JDK which is why it failed. Initially i did

`export JAVA_HOME=readlink -f $(which java)`

So i updated and exported my JAVA_HOME variable with output of `which javac`command. What is interesting is that last part of the error did not display the changed JAVA_HOME value. Why is that?

2. What is this `includeantruntime` and how to get rid of it? I use ant 1.9.2

Comment: Did you run the ant task in the same shell under the same user where you have set JAVA_HOME to JDK before? If not thats your fault. Setting an env var inside a shell, that is not persistent and not shared between other shell sessions!

Comment: They are running in the same shell and same user account on Redhat Linux 6 and i use bash shell. So, the environment variable should be common to both these commands is what i feel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check and update ant configuration file for the  JAVA_HOME settings. It is possible that the value for $JAVA_HOME set for your shell in .bashrc can be overridden in the files /etc/ant.conf, $HOME/.ant/ant.conf, and $HOME/.antrc. If you execute bash -x  it will print debugging information which should help you track down where $JAVA_HOME is being overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its just a matter of where Ant first looks for the java executable (i.e. in the JAVA_HOME variable or somewhere else).

You can test if this is the case by setting the `fork="true"` and the `executable` parameter as described here:
https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html
and see if this is the case.

Also, did you actually found the tools.jar in the JVM you're currently pointing your JAVA_HOME at ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If Ant looks elsewhere for the java executable then why does it work correctly with the first JAVA_HOME setting. 
And yes, I have managed to locate the tools.jar in the directory pointed by `which javac` command. However, the output is a symbolic link to other locations. Is this an issue?

Comment: Sorry, unclear to me what you mean "work correctly with the first JAVA_HOME setting". From your question, I understand that the opposite is true. I don't think that the symbolic link is the issue; this is pretty common on Linux, and as far as I recall, it worked for me previously.